# PHP Multiple Textbox Array POST

Tags: php

```
<form method="post">
<?php
for($i = 1; $i <= 1000; $i++)
{
    for($j = 1; $j <= 100; $j++)
    {
        echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"text" . $j . "[]\" value=\"" . ($i * $j) . "\" />";
    }
}
?>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Why only get 10 rows output when post 1000 rows?
Already set all variable in `php.ini` like `input_max_var`, `max_execution_time`, `max_post_limit` etc...

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [text1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 5
            [5] => 6
            [6] => 7
            [7] => 8
            [8] => 9
            [9] => 10
        )
    [text2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 6
            [3] => 8
            [4] => 10
            [5] => 12
            [6] => 14
            [7] => 16
            [8] => 18
            [9] => 20
        )
    .
    .
    .
    [text100] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [1] => 200
            [2] => 300
            [3] => 400
            [4] => 500
            [5] => 600
            [6] => 700
            [7] => 800
            [8] => 900
            [9] => 1000
        )
)
```

```
memory_limit = -1
post_max_size = 1G
max_execution_time = -1
max_input_time = -1
max_input_vars = -1
suhosin.post.max_vars = -1
suhosin.request.max_vars = -1
```

Comment: probably you forgot to save the file before running it.

Comment: No problems are occur during few days and  100 data are post only..

Comment: it works as expected here.

Comment: Can you give me php.ini configuration?

Comment: This looks like a programmng question!

Comment: php is just default settings. as lines go 5 megabytes is at the big end of the scale, fixing that HTML may help. eg: add `echo "\n";` after `}`

Comment: Are you sure of your loop? Here you will generate 1000 * 100 inputs (100 * text1, 100 * test2, ...), so you will get a tree like text1[0][0] = 1, text1[0][1] = 3, ...

Comment: Yes and show the upper output also..

Answer (score 1):

So you have 100 000 inputs on the page but their names are invalid - there are duplicates on the page. It should be combination of `$i` and `$j`

```
<form method="post">
<?php
for($i = 1; $i <= 1000; $i++)
{
    for($j = 1; $j <= 100; $j++)
    {
        echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"text" . ($j * $i) . "[]\" value=\"" . ($i * $j) . "\" />";
    }
}
?>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: it just a name if i am use only html then also problms occured.